# How to use an Azure Function Binding to send a scheduled Service Bus Queue message?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Function written in node.js that is successfully sending a message to an Azure Service Bus Queue using an output binding.

How can I send a scheduled message into the same Queue still using the binding syntax? I'd rather do this without installing the node.js sdk if at all possible.

The [binding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) doesn't mention scheduled messages.  However, interestingly enough [this comment](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/169) has been made a few times on the Functions github issues repository:

> At least with C# & Node.js (and why not in F#) the Service Bus queue
>   output already supports this e.g. if you create and put multiple
>   messages e.g. to IAsyncCollector or create out BrokeredMessage. Within
>   your outgoing message(s) you can control the scheduled enqueuing time:
>
> `outgoingMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc =
>   DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10)`

Anyway, here's my current code that is working fine for immediately delivering a message:

**function.json**

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name" : "queueOutput",
      "queueName" : "scheduler",
      "connection" : "AZURE_SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "type" : "serviceBus",
      "direction" : "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

  context.log('Scheduler function processed a request.');

  context.bindings.queueOutput = req.body;

  context.res = {
    "status": 200,
    "body": {
      "message": "Successfully sent message to Queue"
    } 
  };

  context.done();

};
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I want to do the same but with Azure Storage Queue. In terms of bindings it looks the same, I can assign an array to the binding variable but don't think I can specify the initial visibility delay

Comment: No, we never did solve this.  It seems as though queues are really just meant for no-response back-end processing.  We still use them, just not for any web responses.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the time based trigger syntax (CRON scheduling)... Assuming I haven't misunderstood the question

```
{
  "name": "function",
  "type": "timerTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
},
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  This isn't a Timer function, but a Scheduled Queue message.  I don't want a recurring event, just a single event in the future using Service Bus, a different interval for each message..